# Julia: How to copy data to another processor in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

How do you move data from one processor to another in julia?

Say I have an array

```
a = [1:10]
```

Or some other data structure. What is the proper way to put it on all other available processors so that it will be available on those processors as the same variable name?

Comment: This seems like it should be a fairly standard request no?

Comment: Your might just get a suggestion to read the documentation: http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/  Is the @everywhere macro what you're looking for?

Comment: I've read the doc and no @everywhere does not do that

Comment: On my system `@everywhere a = [1:10]` does put it on every available processor.  ????

Comment: Thats great, but what if I have some data structure that takes some time to construct, I don't want to have to reconstruct it on every processor, I'd rather do it once and then send it over to all the other ones. The simple `a=[1:10]` array is just an example.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I didn't know how to do this at first, so I spent some time figuring it out.

Here are some functions I wrote to pass objects:

### `sendto`

Send an arbitrary number of variables to specified processes.

New variables are created in the Main module on specified processes. The
name will be the key of the keyword argument and the value will be the
associated value.

```
function sendto(p::Int; args...)
    for (nm, val) in args
        @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
    end
end


function sendto(ps::Vector{Int}; args...)
    for p in ps
        sendto(p; args...)
    end
end
```

#### Examples

```
# creates an integer x and Matrix y on processes 1 and 2
sendto([1, 2], x=100, y=rand(2, 3))

# create a variable here, then send it everywhere else
z = randn(10, 10); sendto(workers(), z=z)
```

### `getfrom`

Retrieve an object defined in an arbitrary module on an arbitrary
process. Defaults to the Main module.

The name of the object to be retrieved should be a symbol.

```
getfrom(p::Int, nm::Symbol; mod=Main) = fetch(@spawnat(p, getfield(mod, nm)))
```

#### Examples

```
# get an object from named x from Main module on process 2. Name it x
x = getfrom(2, :x)
```

### `passobj`

Pass an arbitrary number of objects from one process to arbitrary
processes. The variable must be defined in the `from_mod` module of the
src process and will be copied under the same name to the `to_mod`
module on each target process.

```
function passobj(src::Int, target::Vector{Int}, nm::Symbol;
                 from_mod=Main, to_mod=Main)
    r = RemoteRef(src)
    @spawnat(src, put!(r, getfield(from_mod, nm)))
    for to in target
        @spawnat(to, eval(to_mod, Expr(:(=), nm, fetch(r))))
    end
    nothing
end


function passobj(src::Int, target::Int, nm::Symbol; from_mod=Main, to_mod=Main)
    passobj(src, [target], nm; from_mod=from_mod, to_mod=to_mod)
end


function passobj(src::Int, target, nms::Vector{Symbol};
                 from_mod=Main, to_mod=Main)
    for nm in nms
        passobj(src, target, nm; from_mod=from_mod, to_mod=to_mod)
    end
end
```

#### Examples

```
# pass variable named x from process 2 to all other processes
passobj(2, filter(x->x!=2, procs()), :x)

# pass variables t, u, v from process 3 to process 1
passobj(3, 1, [:t, :u, :v])

# Pass a variable from the `Foo` module on process 1 to Main on workers
passobj(1, workers(), [:foo]; from_mod=Foo)
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for `@spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))`.

Comment: Awesome, glad it works for you, thanks for the macros

Comment: These macros are so useful they should become a package or even part of Julia!

Comment: @user1438310 I made [ParallelDataTransfer.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/ParallelDataTransfer.jl) for this. Currently the tests fail on v0.4.x but pass on v0.5. People can add more to make it even better.

Answer (score 13):

use `@eval @everywhere...` and escape the local variable.  like this:

```
julia> a=collect(1:3)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
  1
  2
  3

julia> addprocs(1)
1-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2

julia> @eval @everywhere a=$a

julia> @fetchfrom 2 a
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```

Answer (score 13):

Just so everyone here knows, I put these ideas together into a package [ParallelDataTransfer.jl](https://github.com/ChrisRackauckas/ParallelDataTransfer.jl) for this. So you just need to do

```
using ParallelDataTransfer
```

(after installing) in order to use the functions mentioned in the answers here. Why? These functions are pretty useful! I added some testing, some new macros, and updated them a bit (they pass on v0.5, fail on v0.4.x). Feel free to put in pull requests to edit these and add more.

Answer (score 2):

To supplement @spencerlyon2 's answer here are some macros:

```
function sendtosimple(p::Int, nm, val)
    ref = @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
end 

macro sendto(p, nm, val)
    return :( sendtosimple($p, $nm, $val) )
end

macro broadcast(nm, val)
    quote
    @sync for p in workers()
        @async sendtosimple(p, $nm, $val)
    end
    end
end
```

The `@spawnat` macro binds a value to a symbol on a particular process

```
julia> @sendto 2 :bip pi/3
RemoteRef{Channel{Any}}(9,1,5340)

julia> @fetchfrom 2 bip
1.0471975511965976
```

The `@broadcast` macro binds a value to a symbol in all processes except `1` (as I found doing so made future expressions using the name copy the version from process `1`)

```
julia> @broadcast :bozo 5

julia> @fetchfrom 2 bozo
5

julia> bozo
ERROR: UndefVarError: bozo not defined

julia> bozo = 3             #these three lines are why I exclude pid 1
3

julia> @fetchfrom 7 bozo
3

julia> @fetchfrom 7 Main.bozo
5
```