# Waiting for a task to be completed on remote processor in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

In a parallel application mimicking distributed inference, I would like to have an "initialization step" where all the "slaves" receive some initial information from the "master" then start their task.

At the moment I have a working implementation based on the `sendTo` function (the code was found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677399/julia-how-to-copy-data-to-another-processor-in-julia) on stack overflow) but I don't think it guarantees that the worker won't start its task before it has received the initial objects.

Here's a rough MWE

```
function sendTo(p::Int; args...)
    for (nm, val) in args
        @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
    end
end

a = 5

addprocs(4)

[sendTo(worker,a=a+randn()) for worker in workers()]

@everywhere begin
    println(a)
end
```

The above "works" but how can I be sure that the commands in the `@everywhere` block does not get executed before the worker has received the definition of `a`?

**Rmk**: for the context I'm working in, I would like to keep two distinct blocks, one that spreads the data and one that does stuff on it.

**Other rmk**: apologies if this is trivial, I'm quite new to dealing with parallelism (and quite new to Julia too)

Comment: You may also be interested in this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287020/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-sync-in-julia/37287021#37287021) which discusses the operation of the `@sync` and `@async` macros and how they can be used to accomplish the types of tasks you are interested in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can just `fetch` the results for every process. See the [example in the docs](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/parallel-computing/)

```
function sendTo(p::Int; args...)
    r = []
    for (nm, val) in args
        s = @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
        vcat([s],r)
    end
end
#...
[fetch(r) for r in [sendTo(worker,a=a+randn()) for worker in workers()]]
```

Comment: This does accomplish the goal.  But isn't there any easier way to do it without this need to add in this extra set of fetching?  I had initially thought  that the sync macro would work, but I haven't actually managed to get it to work.  Perhaps this is just a feature request for a more straightforward way to accomplish this with a macro like sync, if one doesn't exist now.

Comment: If I get you correctly, that would mean that each call would have to request-and-fetch synchronously, making it worthless to do it with multiple processes (actually running in single process/thread would be better since you would be not spending time in overheads)

Comment: [`@sync`](http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/stdlib/parallel/#Base.@sync) __waits__ for the expresion (that being `@async sendTo(...)`, which includes a `@spawnat`) is completed. You're doing the loop synchronously (there are never two workers working at the same time)

Comment: Ok, thank you!  I realized that perhaps I shouldn't be asking questions in the comments section (saw this on a Meta post) and thus moved my query to this page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287020/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-sync/37287021#37287021  I'd welcome any comments, corrections, suggestions, etc. you have!