# Concurrence of Julia Parallel Computing

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I am new to Julia and studying Julia parallel computing recently.
I am still not clear about the accurate mechanism of Julia's parallelism including macros `\@sync` and `\@async` after I read the relevant documents.

The following is the `pmap` function from the [Julia v0.5 documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/parallel-computing/#scheduling):

```
function pmap(f, lst)
    np = nprocs()  # determine the number of processes available
    n = length(lst)
    results = Vector{Any}(n)
    i = 1
    # function to produce the next work item from the queue.
    # in this case it's just an index.
    nextidx() = (idx=i; i+=1; idx)
    @sync begin
        for p=1:np
            if p != myid() || np == 1
                @async begin
                    while true
                        idx = nextidx()
                        if idx > n
                            break
                        end
                        results[idx] = remotecall_fetch(f, p, lst[idx])
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
    results
end
```

Is it possible for different two processors/workers call `nextidx()` at the same time getting the same `idx = j`? If yes, I feel `results[j]` will be computed twice and `result[j+1]` will not be computed.

Thanks very much.

More findings:

```
function f1()
  i=1
  nextidx()=(idx=i;sleep(1);i+=1;idx)
  for p=1:2
    @async begin
      idx=nextidx()
      println(idx)
      end
  end
end
f1()
```

The result is `1 1`.
Through this I find the time periods during which the two tasks call the function `nextidx()` could overlap. So I feel that in the first code,
if `np = 3` (i.e. two workers), and the length `n` of `lst` is very large, say 10^8,
it's possible for the tasks to get the same index.
It may happen just because of a coincidence in time, i.e., the two tasks take the expression `idx = i` at almost the same time point, so the code is not stable.
Am I right?

Comment: consider reading the _excellent_ answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287020/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-sync-in-julia) SO question regarding `\@sync` and `\@async`. in the `pmap` example that you cite, each process obtains `idx` from `nextidx()` separately from other processes.

Comment: I read the answer and now know the basic features of \@sync and \@async. However, I still concern different tasks will might get the same index idx. See my more findings above. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, so long as you schedule jobs correctly. The `pmap` [documentation](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/parallel-computing/#scheduling) points out that the master process schedules the jobs serially; only the parallel *execution* is asynchronous. `pmap` as coded requires no thread locks to ensure correct job scheduling. Adding `sleep` to `nextidx` deliberately breaks this feature and introduces the race condition that you observe. Assuming that all of the processes share state -- which is the purpose of the `nextidx` function -- then the master process will not schedule the same job twice.

Comment: I still have no idea why my worry is unnecessary. Maybe it's because I lack the knowledge of underlying bottom mechanism of Julia and computers including how the above code makes scheduling and what a thread is....
Any way, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: no, your worry is warranted. as you demonstrated, it is not difficult to introduce race conditions into parallel code. but Julia's `pmap` is coded so as to avoid them. see updated answer.

Comment: also, if you find this answer satisfactory, then please consider accepting it.