# async Elixir vs async Julia

Tags: asynchronous, elixir, julia

In Elixir I can run code asynchronously like this

```
defmodule Async do
   def example do
       process_id = Task.async(fn ->
          #some code you want its result later
       end)
       #do some stuff
       async_result = Task.await(process_id)
    end
end
```

and, if i don't need any results I can do like this

```
defmodule Async do
   def example do
       process_id = Task.start_link(fn ->
          #some code you want its result later
       end)
       #do some stuff
       :ok
    end
end
```

What's the equivalent of above in Julia lang?

Comment: take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37287020/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-sync-in-julia

Comment: the best way to do this would be with Tasks, or Channels, (or whatever is the 'async-du-jour' that has survived deprecation -- I don't know, I haven't kept up with all the changes to Julia 1.0).  I answered a question on Channels some time ago that might be useful to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44989053/4183191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you **do not care about the result**, you can use `@async`:

```
function foo()
    sleep(100)
    sum(1:100)
end

julia> @async foo()
Task (runnable) @0x00007f983b9d5f90

julia>
```

in the above example you get back the control of the terminal, without having to wait until the end of the execution of `foo()`

if **you want to know the result**, and keep an asynchronous behavior, you can use [`Task`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/parallel/#Core.Task), [`schedule`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/parallel/#Base.schedule) and [`fetch`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/parallel/#Base.fetch-Tuple%7BChannel%7D) together:

```
julia> a() = sum(1:10000)
a (generic function with 1 method)

julia> b = Task(a)
Task (runnable) @0x00007f983b9d5cf0

julia> schedule(b)
Task (done) @0x00007f983b9d5cf0

julia> fetch(b)
50005000
```

---

Here is a small piece of code I use to illustrate the different behaviors:

```
module async

function example1()
    a() = @async sleep(2)
    b = Task(a)
    schedule(b)
    println(fetch(b))
    sleep(4)
    fetch(b)
end

function example2()
    a() = sleep(2)
    b = Task(a)
    schedule(b)
    fetch(b)
end

function example3()
    a() = sum(1:10000)
    b = Task(a)
    schedule(b)
    fetch(b)
end

end;
```

when I run this code, I get:

```
julia> async.example1()
Task (runnable) @0x00007f983b9d5510
Task (done) @0x00007f983b9d5510

julia> async.example2()

julia> async.example3()
50005000
```

`async.example2()` does not return any result, but keep the terminal busy around 2 seconds since `fetch` waits for the task to complete before giving back the hand.

Comment: `@async` returns a `Task` and can be `fetch`ed too, like `a = @async (sleep(2); "result"); println(fetch(a))`

Comment: That is accurate, I did not notice, thanks ! I realise that my `async.example1()` is a task of a task in fact.