# Trouble fetching remote instance of user-defined type in Julia

Tags: julia

Here's some Julia code:

```
addprocs()
@everywhere begin
    type Test
        values::Array{Any,1}
        addValue::Function
   function Test()
       this = new()
       this.values = Any[]

       this.addValue = function(v)
           push!(this.values,v)
       end

       return this
   end
end
end
@everywhere t = Test()
@everywhere t.addValue(myid())
@spawnat 2 whos()
r = @spawnat 2 t
```

I believe this code defines a Test type on all processes and then creates an instance of that type stored in a variable, called t, on each process. This variable is local to that process. I then use one of the Test methods run in parallel on each process to mutate the local instance of Test. In the line

```
@spawnat 2 whos()
```

we can see that the local t has indeed been updated. However, I get a HUGE error when trying to fetch any of the remote variables t into a RemoteRef. The error message is quite large, but it leads me to believe that the Julia serialization process cannot handle user-defined types. Can anybody lend some insight? Thank You!

Upadate:
A simpler example yielding the same error:

```
addprocs() 
@everywhere begin
 type Test
    values::Array{Any,1}
    addValue::Function
    function Test()
       this = new()
       this.values = Any[]
       this.addValue = function(v)
           push!(this.values,v)
       end
       return this
   end
end
end
t = Test()
R = RemoteRef(2)
put!(R,t)
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why trying to `fetch` that composite object with a `function` field inside, causes the Error..., anyway I encourage you to use Julia way for creating the same functionality:

First of all you don't need to include `addValue` function inside the `Test` type, try to separate data storage from functionality:

```
@everywhere begin
    type Test
        values::Array{Any,1}
        addValue::Function
      function Test()
        this = new()
        this.values = Any[]
        return this
      end
    end
end

@everywhere function addValue(v,t::test)
               push!(t.values,v)
            end
```

then initialize `t` everywhere:

`@everywhere t = Test()`

and mutate t everywhere:

`@everywhere addValue(myid(),t)`

Secondly run getfield() command on desired process to get local variable:

`r = @spawnat 3 getfield(Main,:t)`

check the result:

`assert(fetch(r).values==[3])`

for more details about how to pass variable between processes check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677399/julia-how-to-copy-data-to-another-processor-in-julia).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I did come across the question you linked to, and it does appear that I can fetch and send if I separate methods and properties, per your suggestion.

However, it seems like a bug that the type def I used should not be serializable, right? In general, why should I separate data storage from functionality? Seems like a divergence from OOP, which Julia is supposed to support.

Also, it seems like a hassle to use Symbols or Expr for passing local variables among procs. Do you agree?

Comment: word is that the newest release (v0.4.1) will resolve my error.  :D

Comment: In the case that it looks like a bug, I agree with you. If you like the topic of OOP approach in Julia language, check "Julia and Object-Oriented Programming" topic in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/julia-users