# How to get source directory on secondary workers in Julia?

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I find using `Base.source_dir()` super convenient for `include`ing files into a Julia script because it is easy to load everything using relative paths from the script file. This doesn't work properly with parallelized code. For example, if we have a test file in `/Users/username/test/` called `test.jl`, with the following code:

```
@everywhere println(pwd())
@everywhere println(Base.source_dir())
```

and we run `julia -p 1 test/test.jl` we get

```
/Users/username
    From worker 2:  /Users/username
/Users/username/test
    From worker 2:  nothing
```

what would be the most robust way to `include` another file that is also in the `test` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually use something like this:

```
function sendto(p::Int; args...)
    for (nm, val) in args
        @spawnat(p, eval(Main, Expr(:(=), nm, val)))
    end
end    

SourceDir = Base.source_dir()    

for (idx, pid) in enumerate(workers())
    sendto(pid, SourceDir = SourceDir)
end    

@everywhere include(string(SourceDir, "/", "FileName"))
```

See here ([Julia: How to copy data to another processor in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677399/julia-how-to-copy-data-to-another-processor-in-julia)) for the source of the `sendto()` function as well as a lot of other useful tools for moving data between workers.

Comment: Agreed. I went ahead and changed the title since your solution should work in many situations and it will help me find it when I'll be googling for it in a couple weeks haha.

Comment: See also this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677399/julia-how-to-copy-data-to-another-processor-in-julia) which is where I got the function.  It has a similar `getfrom()` function as well.  I'd actually recommend changing your title back.  Your new one might make the question basically a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: I actually like the `@eval @everywhere` solution a lot in that post

Answer (score 2):

A less generalized, but arguably more elegant solution for this specific case is to the following:

```
source_dir = Base.source_dir()    
@eval @everywhere include(joinpath($source_dir, "test2.jl"))
```

which was adapted from [Julia: How to copy data to another processor in Julia](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677399/julia-how-to-copy-data-to-another-processor-in-julia) as pointed out by @aireties. I'll leave both as solutions.