# Confusing julia behavior. @everywhere macro changes the scope of local variables to global

Tags: parallel-processing, julia, distributed-computing, distributed

I just encountered a very confusing julia behavior. I always thought that variables defined inside a function remain local to that function. But in the following example, the scope changes.

I define a simple function as below

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)

function f()
    @everywhere x = myid()
    @everywhere println("x = ", x)
end
```

Executing the following code

```
f()
```

gives the result

```
x = 1
From worker 2:    x = 2
From worker 3:    x = 3
```

But since x is defined inside the function, I would expect the variable `x` to be not defined outside the function. However, upon executing the following code

```
x
```

I get the result

```
1
```

Even more confusing is the execution of the following code

@fetchfrom 3 x

which again gives

```
1
```

This is super confusing behavior. First, how does x become available outside the function? Second, why are all the processors/cores returning the same value of x? Thank you for your help.

Comment: `@everywhere` always evaluates into `Main` on the process on which it's executed. `@fetchfrom` doesn't work as you expect I think - check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27677399/julia-how-to-copy-data-to-another-processor-in-julia?noredirect=1&lq=1) discussion which gives the functions you want. `fetch(@spawnat(3, getfield(Main, :x)))` returns 3 as expected.